# How to recover /usr/bin/python on Debian when removed by accident

Tags: python, linux, debian

On my Debian system, I removed `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python2.7` by accident. Then I tried to remove all of Python entirely with the `apt-get remove` command and installed it again. Unfortunately, `/usr/bin/python` was not created again as I expected.

As a result, the `python` command cannot be run anymore. So I would like to recover the `/usr/bin/python2.7` on the OS level.

Moreover, when I restart the Debian system, even the GNOME GUI can't be launched anymore; only the tty terminal 8 was available, almost certainly because of the absence of `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: For future note, you don't need to remove a package before being able to force its reinstallation (and for base packages, it's far wiser to leave them present and reinstall over them).

Comment: That said, this is very much a system administration question rather than a software development question (it's not specific to Python, but is a situation you could have with *any* base package in need of installation). From that perspective, [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is probably a better forum.

Comment: Linux uses Python in many places - maybe even `apt-get` uses Python so you may have problem now.

Comment: @furas: both `dpkg` and `apt-get` can operate without Python installed.

Answer (score 7):

`/usr/bin/python` is part of the [`python-minimal` package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/python-minimal/filelist) and `/usr/bin/python2.7` is contained in [`python2.7-minimal`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/python2.7-minimal/filelist), reinstall those packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal python2.7-minimal
```

You can always ask your package manager what package to reinstall, `dpkg -S` lets you search for what package owns a given file:

```
$ dpkg --help | grep -- -S
  -S|--search <pattern> ...        Find package(s) owning file(s).
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7
python-minimal: /usr/bin/python
python2.7-minimal: /usr/bin/python2.7
```

or you can use the [Debian package web interface](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fpython&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any).

If `apt-get install` still fails with errors, then the package scripts could well be requiring Python to still work. Your next step is to then download the `.deb` files manually and copy those into place until you *can* run the `apt-get install`.

Determine your system architecture:

$ dpkg --print-architecture
   amd64

then visit the [`python2.7-minimal`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python2.7-minimal) and [`python-minimal`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-minimal) package pages; on each page click on the matching architecture link under the *Download* header. You are taken to a list of mirrors. Download a copy of the `.deb` files from a suitable mirror or copy the URL to use `curl -O <url>` to download it directly to your affected computer.

Then unpack those files with:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/rescue
$ dpkg-deb -x python-minimal_*.deb rescue
$ dpkg-deb -x python2.7-minimal_*_amd64.deb rescue
```

You can now copy the required files from `/tmp/rescue/usr/bin` to your system.

Comment: I tried your solution today after removing `/usr/bin/python` on purpose, but unfortunately the command you suggested did not work at all. It prompted an error: `Errors were encountered while processing: python-minimal E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: @Rui: oh dear, so dpkg requires Python to be installed.. Let's see what I can uncover.